# .htaccess modrewrite only from domain stem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

code in original question edited!

How do I rewrite only from the domain stem.

I am using .htaccess to rewrite urls for a php-based site.

I would like to rewrite from:

```
www.example.com/dir1/dir2/page.htm
```

to:

```
www.example.com/index.php/var1=dir1&var2=dir2&var3=page
```

The code I have works well

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)\.htm$ index.php?type=cdi23&lev=$1&sec=$2&vid=$3 [QSA,L]
```

BUT it also rewrites urls with any number of PREVIOUS directories. For example:

```
www.example.com/unwanted/unwanted/dir1/dir2/page.htm
```

will also rewrite to:

```
www.example.com/index.php/var1=dir1&var2=dir2&var3=page
```

How do I stop URLs with extra directories from triggering the rewrite? They should just return a 404

Comment: Show access **and** rewrite logs. This seems inplausible or incomplete (domain name in the request path).

Comment: I agree with @mario, the shown rewrite rule certainly won't match the requests at all.

Comment: @mario, sorry I accidentally copied one of the failed code versions.  Question now edited to include the code that i am actually using.

Comment: Still unanswerable without rewrite log. Anchoring and patterns wouldn't trigger multiple rewrite loops, unless there are virtual/real dirs and spread .htaccess files involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching non-greedy:

```
^([^/\.]+?)/([^/\.]+?)/([^/\.]+?)
```